# How to access Mobx Store using my file structore below

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Supposing I have this .jsx files which basically contains all my existing store.

user-access.jsx

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';
export default new class UserAccess{
   @observable page_access = [];
}
```

stores.jsx

```
import { UserAccess } from './stores/user-access';

const stores = {
    "UserAccess" : UserAccess,
};

export default stores;
```

index.jsx

```
import stores from './stores';

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider stores = { stores } >
     <Router .... />
 </Provider>
```

And I want to access it in my component, how do I do it? This is what I have so far.

```
@inject('stores') @observer
export default class PageHeader extends React.Component{
........

}
```

How do I access the obervable page_access and how do I inject the store itself in my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already have it injected. You can access injected stores from props. And the component will naturally react to changes in the store as long as you have the observer decorator.

I see some minor issues that I'm not sure are copy paste related (you export default class in user-access but import a named instance?) But assuming that stuff is working the code below should work.

```
@inject('stores') @observer
export default class PageHeader extends React.Component{
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.stores.UserAccess)
  }
}
```